# How to select and copy text from Text widget in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I select and copy text from Text widget in flutter web?

I use Clipboard, but it doesnot work.

```
child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: _data.url))
                                  .catchError((e) {
                              }).whenComplete(() {
                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('已复制'),
                                ));
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              '复制',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33470

Answer (score 0):

use Builder Widget

```
  child: Builder(builder: (context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: url))
            .catchError((e) {})
            .whenComplete(() {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('已复制'),
          ));
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        '复制',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 40,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
```